# async/await vs callback resolution order, given shared asynchronicity

Tags: node.js

If async/await & callbacks are both asynchronous, why are async/await resolved before callbacks?

For example (hypothetical, in practice its obviously not so cut-and-dry)

```
// classic callback
doSomething("./some-path", (err, data) => {...})

// This resolves with higher priority
await someAsyncFunction()
```

Comment: What do you mean the second one "resolves" with higher priority.  Do you mean that `someAsyncFunction()` executes before `doSomething()` is done?  Or, it finishes first?  If so, neither of those observations have anything to do with the answer you've accepted which is probably wrong.

Comment: @jfriend00 My apologies, the question wasn't clear enough about this, but this was a question about node and node's implementations directly, not javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved/Rejected promises flow through the PromiseJobQueue and that queue is serviced BEFORE other items in the event loop such as file I/O completion callbacks or network completion callbacks or timers.

So, if you have a promise that is getting resolved in some manner that does not use a callback in the event loop (which is generally not the case), then it can get serviced in a higher priority way than other event loop-based callbacks.

This makes the most difference when you have multiple chained promises, such as `fn().then().then().then()` or multiple `await` statements in sequence.  In those circumstances, even though `.then()` and `await` will let the stack unwind, the promises will have priority over the things in the event loop.

But, if you build up a complex function that returns a promise and inside that complex function, you're using I/O callbacks in your own code in order to resolve/reject the promise, then you won't see that "fast lane" effect from the promise because it doesn't get resolved until the event loop services its callback anyway.

Comment: You beat me to the punch, I was authoring this same answer.

Comment: The thing to understand is the Promise Job-Queue. By adding this, ECMAScript fundamentally changed the way asynchronous code is written & handled by programmers. It gave developers control over what is async and what is not. Another important detail is that just because a function calls a cb, doesn't mean the cb is called  asynchronously. From what I remember, and quote me if I am wrong please, those who build the JS engines (_i.e._ **V8, SpiderMonkey**, etc...) had some control over which cb's were being called asynchronously. A notorious example of a non async cb is `forEach()`.

Comment: @jD3V - Yes, lots of callbacks are synchronous like `.forEach()` and `.map()` and `.filter()`.  That's part of the Javascript spec and not up to people who implement JS engines.  But, callbacks for asynchronous functions like `fs.readFile()` in nodejs or the various notifications you get from `XMLHttpRequest` in a browser are asynchronous and necessarily flow through the event loop because they have underlying asynchronous operations associated with them.